# How to dynamically remove script from a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

What i am trying is - 
http://jsfiddle.net/jhrz9/1/

to remove the script generated when someone clicks the button #goBack button
Now i am able to create and append script and style tags when the user clicks the #runMyCode 
But as soon as i go back to the previous screen using #goBack button the script stays on the screen, now what i want to do is to remove that script and create another one again when i click the #runMyCode button

Now i am trying this -

```
var newScript = document.createElement('script'); ;
var newTextNode=document.createTextNode($("#jsTextArea").val());
newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
newScript.appendChild(newTextNode);
document.body.appendChild(newScript);
$('#goBack').click(function(){
newTextNode.parentNode.removeChild(newTextNode);
});
```

But for some reason it is not working....

Comment: Note that removing a script tag does not remove the script once it's loaded into memory, so this is futile!

Comment: Why the odd mix of vanilla Javascript and jQuery?

Comment: I was working on a worklight android app thats why had to use them for simplicity

Comment: @adeneo i tried now , when i update my script in its container and then try to update the content , i see that the content in that script tag is replaced by new content, now i dont know if that script is still in memory or not? is it or it aint?

Comment: *[Yo, dawg](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/xzibit-yo-dawg)*, Unless the code is executed in a separate context, such as an `iframe`, it will still be in memory, and possibly even be able to tamper with your code. Since you already have this in a JSFiddle, try to fiddle around with it and see how it works.

Comment: Okay... thanks for telling, do you have knowledge about abdroid apps using ibm worklight, I just wanted to know if I can use an iframe on mobile apps or not???

Answer (score 1):

you have to give the script an id.

```
$("#runMyCode").click(function(){
   $("#resultContainer").html($("#htmlTextArea").val());
   var newScript = document.createElement('script');
   newScript.id = "goback_script";
   var newTextNode=document.createTextNode($("#jsTextArea").val());
   newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
   newScript.appendChild(newTextNode);
   document.body.appendChild(newScript);
   var newStyle = document.createElement('style');
   var newTextNode2=document.createTextNode($("#cssTextArea").val());
   newStyle.type = 'text/css';
   newStyle.appendChild(newTextNode2);
   document.body.appendChild(newStyle);
});
$('#goBack').click(function(){
   var script = document.getElementById("goback_script");
   script.parentElement.removeChild(script);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e3PvY/)

Comment: This doesn't work ! The question is about removing the script from the page and not just the script tag.

Comment: You should also manually rewrite every value and function stored in that script to null if the intent is to make the contents unreadable.

Comment: Removing the script tag does not solve the original problem.