# How to turn off jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

Not sure if I asked the question right, but what I want to achieve is: I am using masonry plugin on responsive website, and I want it only to work for desktop. So I'm using this code to run the plugin:

```
var $container = $('#container');
$container.masonry({
        columnWidth: 200,
        itemSelector: '.item'
});
```

For screens smaller than 900px (on resize and load) I don't want this plugin to work. I have this code, but not sure what I should put inside to stop the plugin from running, if possible? (I'm detecting by css rather than window width)

```
$(window).on("load resize", function() {
    if ($("#logo").css("left") == "none" ){
      //stop plugin from running
    }
});
```

Comment: CSS can't turn the script off, so you'll have to check the width of the page and remove the script element on window resize

Comment: but how to remove the script?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815857/how-to-dynamically-remove-script-from-a-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://desandro.github.io/masonry/docs/methods.html#destroy

```
$('#container').masonry( 'destroy' );
```

Comment: I accepthed this as an answer because it worked, but I have this error in firebug: cannot call methods on masonry prior to initialization; attempted to call 'destroy'

Comment: You are calling this code before you initialize the plugin. Need to run it after that.

Comment: I am running this code only for big screens, and remove it for mobiles, and I created conditional in `$(window).on("load resize", function() {` so when I am resizing the window sometimes the it runs before initialize, sometimes after, depending on starting browser screens size point - if that makes sense. Is there any way around that?

Comment: Sorry for late answer. Long week of work. My solution to that would be to check the browser size before you ever init the plugin. Only init the plugin if the size of your browser is to what you are wanting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
if($(window).width()<900){
    $('#masonry').masonry( 'destroy' );
}
```

and you can reinitialize your script using your initialize function which you
used to start your function

Answer (score 0):

you can check the width of the window by:

```
var ww = $(window).width();

if (ww <= 900px) {
    $('#container').masonry( 'destroy' );
}
```

i would suggest that you also use a [debounce](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) function in your resize function so it doesn't listen all the time.

greetings timotheus